# Make Nav Menu smaller

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, typo3-8.7.x

Can someone help me with my Nav of the following Webpage: [104.40.188.194](http://104.40.188.194/)

When I change the height, it's not working fine.

1 Menu 50 to 60px

2 Menu 65px

Comment: Not sure what you mean - can you specify the elements?

Comment: The navigation and the metanav.

Comment: Metanav being the topmost bar with the mail icon, DE, EN?

Comment: Yes this is the metanav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.navbar has a min-height of 70px - you will need to reduce that to 60px. From there, you'll need:

```
@media (min-width: 992px){
  .navbar-transition .navbar-header-main .navbar-brand, .navbar-transition .navbar-main > li > .navbar-text, .navbar-transition .navbar-main > li > a {
    line-height: 64px;
    height: 65px;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li > a{
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 17px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Works fine, One last question do you have a plan why the metanav start moving at ca. 976 px?

Comment: There's a float: left on .navbar-nav > li that's only at a min-width of 992px - you need that float left to keep them all on the same row, so you can just pull that declaration out of the media query.